# I can't log in with codeception and Selenium

Tags: cookies, prestashop, codeception

I have a small issue, I'm trying to use Codeception to run my first test phase. To do this, I'm using a Selenium2 and PrestaShop.

The first step I'm trying to achieve is to log in the backoffice of PrestaShop.

But it seems that it does not want to connect to PrestaShop Backoffice. and I get redirected to the login page!

Does anyone know where this can come from? 
It seems that there is something with cookies or session, but I don't know how to fix this!

Edit : Here are my codes :

Selenium.suite.yml :

```
class_name: SeleniumGuy
modules:
    enabled: 
        - SeleniumHelper
        - Selenium2
    config: 
        Selenium2:
            url: 'http://localhost/Sites/PrestaShop1.5.4/'
            browser: 'firefox'
            capabilities:
                unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
```

codeception.yml

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_log
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_helpers
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    suite_class: \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
    colors: false
    memory_limit: 1024M
    log: true
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: ''
            user: 'root'
            password: 'root'
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

In the folder tests/Selenium I have
PrestaShopGlobalCest.php

```
    <?php
use \SeleniumGuy;

class PrestaShopModuleListCest
{
    // tests
    public function install_the_module(SeleniumGuy $I) {
        PrestaShopGlobalHelper::loginBackoffice($I);
        PrestaShopGlobalHelper::goToPage($I, 'modules');
    }
}
```

_bootstrap.php

```
<?php
    Codeception\Util\Autoload::registerSuffix('Helper', __DIR__.'/../helpers/Selenium');
?>
```

In tests/helpers/Selenium I have

PrestaShopGlobalHelper

```
<?php

use \SeleniumGuy;

class PrestaShopGlobalHelper
{
    static $mainTabID = array(
        'modules' => 'maintab15'
    );
    static $menuLink = array(
        'modules' => '#maintab15 .submenu li:first'
    );

    // tests
    static public function loginBackOffice(SeleniumGuy $I) {
        $I->wantTo('Login in Backoffice');
        $I->amOnPage('/bb');
        PrestaShopGlobalHelper::login($I);
    }

    static public function login(SeleniumGuy $I, $login = '****', $pass = '****')
    {
        $I->fillField('#email',$login);
        $I->fillField('#passwd',$pass);
        $I->click('Connexion');
    }

    static public function goToPage(SeleniumGuy $I, $page)
    {
        $I->moveMouseOver('#'.self::$mainTabID[$page]);
        $I->click(self::$menuLink[$page]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found out what the problem was :

I've added an explicit wait time in Selenium2.yml. 
The next step is to add an implicit wait in Selenium2 Module but this is not configurable, and I had no time to try out to extend the class : 
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/620#issuecomment-26525462